# Parse stdout of containers in Openshift

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to Openshift/Kubernetes, so I hope that I can explain my use case well enough.

I have a Docker image of a small "program", it can be summarised as the following: it tails -f a log file, and when something that matches a regex specified in config is found, it sends an email to someone. Something like monitoring a production log of an application and sending an email with a stacktrace to the Ops team if one is printed in the application log.

This works fine when my application log is produced via let's say a Java EE on Weblogic app running on the host, or a log produced by another docker container but saved to a bind mounted filesystem, therefore accessible (if mounted) by the "monitoring" container.

Now I need to deploy this image to monitor 2-3 microservices running in Openshift. These microservices log to stdout, and I do not have privileges to mount a path owned by root like /var/lib/docker/containers/[container-id]/[container-id]-json.log to the "monitoring" container.

What is the best way to be able to parse the microservices logs? I am allowed to change their logback config to have them log to stdout AND to an emptyDir volume for example, and create a Pod with the microservice+volume+monitoring container.

Thank you everyone for your suggestions,
Roberto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's fluentd for Docker as log agreggator. However, you cannot install only fluentd with openshift's ansible installer (see [deploying-efk](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/aggregate_logging.html#deploying-the-efk-stack)). You can install fluentd logging driver on docker host manually (see [fluentd-logging-driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/fluentd/)). [There](https://www.fluentd.org/guides/recipes/docker-logging)'s 'getting started' about docker host configuration.
Then you can use any [output plugin](https://www.fluentd.org/plugins/all#input-output) to store logs

Comment: Dear Oligzeev, I did look into it in the past, because afaik there already is a Elasticsearch, Fluentd and Kibana stack installed, in production at least. Those "modules" are maintained by another team, so I cannot really access those except for the Kibana UI. I guess that I'd need to ask the team that managed Fluentd that forwards to ES and Kibana if they can also use their fluentd to collect to files via the use_file configuration of Fluentd?

Comment: You can integrate your java application with elastic (what is preferred from architecture perspectives) or ask to add output plugin to fluentd to forward messages to your store (file, db etc)

Comment: The latter seems feasible, what I didn't really understand about the docker logging drivers is if I could use more than one, I did some tests with the default json-file vs the syslog driver, but it ended up logging either to the json file or the syslog-ng server, not both, so I suspected that I couldn't change the logging drivers without crippling the other flow (the Fluend/ES/Kibana managed by the platform owners).

Comment: You shouldn't configure other logging-driver (if EFK is already there) because you can forward logs on fluentd side with additional output_plugins

Answer (score 0):

how can I forward Logs to a single file on my Filesystem?