# Openshift applications logs forward to a single file

Tags: logging, openshift, fluentd, efk

how can I forward my applications logs in Openshift to a single file on my filesystem? It is possible with fluentd?

BR

Comment: Yes, you can (check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60227369/parse-stdout-of-containers-in-openshift/60228908#60228908). There're a lot of output_plugins to forward log messages

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing Operator.
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/logging/config/efk-logging-elasticsearch.html